# How to center the contents of a webview

Tags: html, css, react-native

I understand that this question may seem trivial but this problem is causing me trouble for almost 2 days.

I have a React Native application that uses webview to render the html contents based on the link provided.

Here's my code:

```
const renderHtml = () => {
   return (
    '<div style="display: flex; background: #efefef; flex-direction: column; align-items: center;">' 
       + htmlContent +
    '</div>'
          );
};
```

As you can see I wrapped the `htmlContent` inside a div since there's no way to modify the stylings of the elements that is returned by it. The content contains `p tags`, `a tags` and `img tags`.

The problem is only the `p tags` and `a tags` are aligned center. `img tags` remains on the left portion of the screen. I tried to used `text-align: center` but since the images are odd numbers the last image didn't align to other images.

Just like this:

```
Image 1    Image 2
Image 3    Image 4
Image 5    Image 6
     Image 7
```

What I wanted to happen is to align Image 7 on Images 1, 3 and 5

Answer (score 0):

You can use containerStyle and tagStyle for react-native-render-html if last item has a id you can use the **idsStyles** prop all props link : https://meliorence.github.io/react-native-render-html/api/renderhtmlprops

```
<HTML
  tagsStyles={{
    img: htmlImageStyle
  }}
  containerStyle={htmlContainerStyle}
  source={{ html: html }}
/>
```

Comment: I tried to use it but still doesn't align the images